# How to check the code of a Blender Operator?

Tags: source-code

So we can access UI element of blender's python code,  but what If I want to inspect, check or study the code of existing operator in blender? Is it accessible anywhere?

Comment: Blender is open source, everything is by definition accessible, if not directly from code repositories https://developer.blender.org/diffusion

Comment: do I need to get the source code to check the operator code?

Comment: That depends whether the operator is from a Python add-on or if it's implement in the C or C++ code of Blender itself. The former can be inspected without the source code of Blender.

Comment: Where do I find them? I guess for the python one, I guess, operator like "Separate" or "select linked" probably is done in python? or if its in C or C++ then nothing i could do I think.

But it would be nice to be able to study existing operator and how they work

Comment: You may want to enable the Python tooltips and the developer extras (see [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html#prefs-interface-dev-extras)). Select linked `bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()` is implemented in [`editmesh_select.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_select.c) as `MESH_OT_select_linked`.